# I can't create table using another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inserted 5 records in table `STAFF` and tried creating a new table using `STAFF` table but I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Default syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
    SELECT column1, column2,...
    FROM existing_table_name
    [ WHERE ....; ]
```

My SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF3 AS
    SELECT *
    FROM STAFF
```

I don't know where I wrong, How could I fix this ?

Comment: For **SQL Server**, you need to use `SELECT * INTO STAFF3 FROM STAFF` - [official MS docs on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: If you want to create a new table as data in another table - use this syntax


```sql

SELECT
     column1
    ,column2
    ,columnN
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable;
```

you just can't call `CREATE` in this case

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE TABLE` statements cannot use `SELECT` queries as a data source. Your options are to either use a **View** (`CREATE VIEW As`) or a [`SELECT INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement.

Comment: Tks Bro @joel coehoorn